# Order of operations clarification

Tags: probability

I want to make sure I am right in my thinking.

The order of operations:

1. Parentheses first
2. Exponents (i.e. Powers and Square Roots, etc.)
3. Multiplication and Division (left-to-right)
4. Addition and Subtraction (left-to-right)

When there is a mix of variables like in the denominator of the below equation you see $\sqrt{2πσ^2}$. My initial thought is to multiply $σ^2$ and then multiply the result like this $2*π*result$ where `result` refers to the result of $σ^2$. Then after all that is done square the result of 2*π*result.

i.e. should I calculate it like this $2*π*(σ^2)$ or this $(2*π*σ)^2$

Question: Is my understanding of the order of operations correct?

[image]